# Add manually rows to DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that reads all the data that should be displayed from a database, this works fine, but **I want to add two more rows manually**. How can I do this?

This is my form and where I want to add these two rows is at the end:

[image]

Code:

```
        strsql = "";
        strsql = strsql + " SELECT  CARACT, DENOMI";
        strsql = strsql + " FROM    TC";
        strsql = strsql + " WHERE   CARACT >= '500' AND CARACT != 'MAT' 
        AND CARACT != 'KGN' AND CARACT != 'LON' AND CARACT != 'MAR' AND 
        CARACT != 'PES' AND CARACT != 'T-P' ORDER BY CARACT";

        comando = new SqlCommand(strsql, conexion);
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
        table = new DataTable();

        comando.CommandText = strsql;
        table.Columns.Clear();
        table.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(table);

        conexion.Close();

        DataRow rowD = new DataRow();
        rowD.Cells[0].Value = "Peso%";
        rowD.Cells[1].Value = "Peso%";
        table.Rows.Add(rowD);
        return table;
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to fill a datagrid with rows. Please show that code.

Comment: @GSerg I simply read the data from another dataTable that reads the information from a database. I updated the post with some code but is the only what I am doing to get all the values shown.

Comment: Add the two rows to that other dataTable?

Comment: @GSerg edited again the post with all code. Look table returns that information and at the end I am trying to add a new row with values "%Peso"

Comment: so it looks like it should work. Do you have any error when adding rows manually?

Comment: @oleksa I edited the post again because I have to create a DataRow not a DataGridViewRow. And now how can I add a value to this row?

Comment: you can add new row like `table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Peso%", "Peso%" })` providing row values in the array. Rows are using columns defined for the table.

Comment: @oleksa Is working, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to add Rows is:

var newRow = table.Rows.Add();

newRow["ColuEmail"] = "rb.coqueiro@gmail.com";

newRow["ColumClientName"] = "Renato Coqueiro";